# How to read parquet file into pandas from Azure blob store

Tags: python, azure, jupyter, parquet

I need to read and write parquet files from an Azure blob store within the context of a Jupyter notebook running Python 3 kernel.

I see code for working strictly with parquet files and python and other code for grabbing/writing to an Azure blob store but nothing yet that put's it all together.

Here is some sample code I'm playing with:

`from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='testdata', account_key='key-here')
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(container_name='mycontainer', blob_name='testdata.parquet')`

This last line with throw an encoding-related error.
I've played with [storefact](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/1510) but coming up short there.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi,would you please post the complete error trace?

Comment: Got the same issue, 5 months later.  Did you get a resolution to it?

Answer (score 0):

To access the file you need to access the azure blob storage first.

```
storage_account_name = "your storage account name"
storage_account_access_key = "your storage account access key"
```

Read path of parquet file into variable

```
commonLOB_mst_source = "Parquet file path"
file_type = "parquet"
```

Connect to blob storage

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
  storage_account_access_key)
```

Read Parquet file into dataframe

```
df = spark.read.format(file_type).option("inferSchema", "true").load(commonLOB_mst_source)
```